# conversion of utf-8 string to hex number strange problem

Tags: c++, utf-8

I need a reliable way to convert utf-8 string to hex. (I work with latex encoding)

My initial unicode string as I see from vs debug is

```
std::string symb  = вЋ§;
```

And I know that in latex compiler (and adobe illustrator) this thing corresponds to the hex representation "f8f1".
It seems to me I have a problem with signed and unsigned int somewhere.
What I do is as follows:

```
#include <codecvt> // for std::codecvt_utf8
#include <locale>  // for std::wstring_convert

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv_utf8_utf32;

std::u32string unicode_codepoints = conv_utf8_utf32.from_bytes(symb); // converts utf-8 to unicode

std::vector<std::string> array_of_symbols;
for (int i = 0; i < unicode_codepoints.length(); i++) 
{
    int symb1 = conv_utf8_utf32.from_bytes(symb)[i];
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << symb1;
    std::string res(ss.str());      
    std::string res1 = "0x" + res;
    array_of_symbols.push_back(res1);

}
```

But instead of obtaining f8f1 I got a different number.
In fact, already the variable unicode_codepoints has the "wrong" chart_32_t variable equal to 9127 (yet correct unicode representation, see the red symbol in fig.1).

[image: fig. 1]

The "correct" variable yielding f8f1 should, as it seems, be negative.

What surprises here, is that this code works for almost all other situations. Could someone explain what is wrong here?

And finally, why I'm so sure that the correct representation is f8f1, because the final render of this symbol in svg looks like this (see fig.2) [image: fig 2] and the encoding in the right upper corner.

Comment: How can `вЋ§` become `F8F1` as UTF-8? It should be 6 bytes in total, like `0xD0 0xB2`, `0xD0 0x8B` and `0xC2 0xA7`, or am I missing something?

Comment: This what I don't get either. May be they should be combined somewhow? What the debugger tells me is that all three symbols has char numbers: -30, -114 and -89 respectively. Yet somehow they are stored in unicode_codepoints as a single int 9127 (as you see from fig.1). I think I'm missing smth.

Comment: the working example is symbol "оЃ®" (which is parsed by the code correctly). Codepoints representation is 57454. And the hex number is "e06e" which is correct.

Comment: `U+F8F1`  is  a [private use area codepoint](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf) and its UTF-8 encoding is `EF A3 B1`.

Comment: -30, -114, -89 are the 8-bit 2s complement (signed char) equivalents of E2 8E A7 which is the UTF-8 encoding of U+23A7 (9127 decimal), which is [`LEFT CURLY BRACKET UPPER HOOK`](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf) or ⎧, which seems to be the character you want, not U+F8F1.  `вЋ§` is the `cp1251` decoding of E2 8E A7.  Are you using an Eastern European/Russian version of Windows?

Comment: Indeed, I do use russian windows. It seems you understands the problem. Could you explain why this is happening?